# how to correctly connect two pcie 4.0 nvme disks on X570 AORUS MASTER

Tags: ssd, pci-express, nvme

I found out my second SSD disk to be slow and I wonder whether it is connected to the best way possible to my motherboard. I've read the manual but honestly I don't understand the sharing of PCIe links. All components (graphic card and both SSD disks) are PCIe 4.0 but the reading speed of the second disk is about 200 - 500 MB.

The disk is 70% full.

How would you suggest to correctly connect graphic card and 2 SSD disks?

My Configuration:

Motherboard: X570 AORUS MASTER (https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/X570-AORUS-MASTER-rev-10/sp#sp, manual (pdf) - https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_x570-aorus-master_1002_e.pdf?v=30c7ecc8f9bc0e464b65a4062dd58841)

Graphic card: AMD Radeon RX 5500 XT Challenger D 8G OC (https://www.asrock.com/Graphics-Card/AMD/Radeon%20RX%205500%20XT%20Challenger%20D%208G%20OC/)

First SSD (fast): Force Series Gen.4 PCIe MP600 1TB NVMe M.2 SSD (https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Storage/M-2-SSDs/Force-Series%E2%84%A2-Gen-4-PCIe-NVMe-M-2-SSD/p/CSSD-F1000GBMP600)

Second SSD (slow): WD BLACK SN850 NVMe SSD (https://www.westerndigital.com/products/internal-drives/wd-black-sn850-nvme-ssd#WDS100T1X0E)

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Please, add to your post what the **OS specifications** you're running on that computer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I guess I have found the cause of the problem, so posting here in case anyone else have the same issue.

It was basically an issue on WD side:

https://www.pcgamer.com/wd-is-fixing-a-bug-that-makes-black-sn850-ssds-run-slow-on-x570-motherboards/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).